# Connect Classic SPO subsite to O365 Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, share, office-365-groups

I have a SP classic site on SP online. I have a O365 Group that will need to connect to subsite. Is this possible? Or is it only able to connect to the SCA site level?

As I have SCA access, there is an option in the config menu to "connect to new O365 group" but this is disabled by the admin level and cant be changed, so the option to connect this is not available.   Also this is a test site, in the future there will be 34 subsites. With needing to connect to 34 different groups.

Before the question is asked? No, were not using modern sites. This due  to the clients requirements.

Is there any other suggestions how this can be completed in SP online classic sites?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only top level sites can be connected to O365 groups, not subsites. You'd have to promote your subsites to separate site collections, and then run the "connect to new O365 group" command for each one.

By "promote subsites to site collections", there is not an OOB tool for this, so this step is not trivial. There are 3rd party tools to help move all the content from a subsite to a site collection.